# Azure Data Explorer - Prevent duplicate data ingestion

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have some data coming from sensors and pulled using a REST API. The source data looks like that (JSON array):

```
[
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": ".....",
        "sensor_id": 937,
        ...
        "timestamp": "2023-04-26T09:20:34.825Z"
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": ".....",
        "sensor_id": 722,
        ...
        "timestamp": "2023-04-26T09:20:34.825Z"
    },
    ...
]
```

Logically, each row could be identified by the couple `<sensor_id,timestamp>` which should be unique.

Data should be retrieved every 15 minutes, but it is not guaranteed that every 15 minutes data has been refreshed at source. Hence I must prevent duplicate inserts into the cluster at record level. In particular: every duplicated <sensor_id, timestamp> couple must be ignored when ingesting into the ADX table.

Reading the documentation I noticed there are two main solutions:

- Using `.set-or-replace` command (needs the ingest from query ingestion scenario)
- Using a custom update policy bound to the `.ingest` command

In both cases this not seems a straightforward solution and I will need some temporary tables to do the job. Could you help me to find a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple tactics for handling duplicates, all of which are documented here: [Handle duplicate data in Azure Data Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/dealing-with-duplicates). You'll need to choose the one that is most suitable for your scenario & appetite.

Comment: Eventually, I opted for the materialized view. Thanks!